# Ho to play loom embedded video in java in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to play a embedded video of loom in my android application.
I have tried VideoView but that doesn't work it says can't play this video any workaround for that.
Below is my code done in videoview

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String videoUrl = "YOUR_LOOM_LINK";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

        // sets the resource from the
        // videoUrl to the videoView
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        // creating object of
        // media controller class
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        // sets the anchor view
        // anchor view for the videoView
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        // sets the media player to the videoView
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

        // sets the media controller to the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        // starts the video
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the workaround You can't play using embedded link of loom use webview to play the video.

```
package com.mokshasolutions.hastekhelte.common;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import java.util.Objects;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String videoUrl = "YOUR_LINK";
    private WebView webView;
    String url;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
      
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String 
                    url) {
                    // Prevent the WebView from navigating to clicked links
                    return true;
                }
            });
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // Load your desired webpage
            webView.loadUrl(videoUrl);
       
    }

}
```